# How to check for letter occurrences in a string?

Tags: c++

I am a complete c++ beginner and this knowledge sort of comes from other languages I tried to learn. The code below is a function from a morse code translator that I am trying to build and I am pretty sure that this is not even close to "a good way" of doing it. My question is, how would I make the program look through the the string that the user typed in and change each occurrence of the letter to morse.

```
string  ReplaceAll(std::string str, const std::string& from, const std::string& to){
size_t start_pos = 0;
while ((start_pos = str.find(from, start_pos)) != std::string::npos) {
    str.replace(start_pos, from.length(), to);
    start_pos += to.length(); // Handles case where 'to' is a substring of 'from'
}
return str;}


void Translate(string s) {
static string s2 = ReplaceAll(string(s), std::string("a"), std::string(".- "));
static string s3 = ReplaceAll(string(s2), std::string("b"), std::string("-... "));
static string s4 = ReplaceAll(string(s3), std::string("c"), std::string("-.-. "));
static string s5 = ReplaceAll(string(s4), std::string("d"), std::string("-.. "));
static string s6 = ReplaceAll(string(s5), std::string("e"), std::string(". "));
static string s7 = ReplaceAll(string(s6), std::string("f"), std::string("..-. "));
static string s8 = ReplaceAll(string(s7), std::string("g"), std::string("--. "));
static string s9 = ReplaceAll(string(s8), std::string("h"), std::string(".... "));
static string s10 = ReplaceAll(string(s9), std::string("i"), std::string(".. "));
static string s11 = ReplaceAll(string(s10), std::string("j"), std::string(".--- "));
static string s12 = ReplaceAll(string(s11), std::string("k"), std::string("-.- "));
static string s13 = ReplaceAll(string(s12), std::string("l"), std::string(".-.. "));
static string s14 = ReplaceAll(string(s13), std::string("m"), std::string("-- "));
static string s15 = ReplaceAll(string(s14), std::string("n"), std::string("-. "));
static string s16 = ReplaceAll(string(s15), std::string("o"), std::string("--- "));
static string s17 = ReplaceAll(string(s16), std::string("p"), std::string(".--. "));
static string s18 = ReplaceAll(string(s17), std::string("q"), std::string("--.- "));
static string s19 = ReplaceAll(string(s18), std::string("r"), std::string(".-. "));
static string s20 = ReplaceAll(string(s19), std::string("s"), std::string("... "));
static string s21 = ReplaceAll(string(s20), std::string("t"), std::string("- "));
static string s22 = ReplaceAll(string(s21), std::string("u"), std::string("..- "));
static string s23 = ReplaceAll(string(s22), std::string("v"), std::string("...- "));
static string s24 = ReplaceAll(string(s23), std::string("w"), std::string(".-- "));
static string s25 = ReplaceAll(string(s24), std::string("x"), std::string("-..- "));
static string s26 = ReplaceAll(string(s25), std::string("y"), std::string("-.-- "));
static string s27 = ReplaceAll(string(s26), std::string("z"), std::string("--.. "));

cout << s27 << endl;
```

}

Comment: Make a map of characters and strings that maps letters to their morse code representations. Create some sort of buffer, e.g. an `std::stringstream`. Iterate over the characters in the input, and for each character, look it up in the map and write the corresponding value to the buffer. Do what you want with the buffer; turn it into a string, print it, etc.

Comment: You probably rather want to use a `std::map<char,std::string>` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is a better solution to build a `std::map` with the replacements and go through all the characters and build a new string. With your solution characters like `.`, `-`, `!` are in the result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<char, const char*> Replacements;

std::string Translate(const Replacements& r, std::string s) 
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(s.size() * 5); // optional: reserve guessed number of elements for new string

    // for every element of the string
    for (char c : s)
    {
        // search for replacement
        Replacements::const_iterator iter = r.find(c);
        if (iter != r.end())
        {
            // found replacement
          result += iter->second;
          result.push_back(' ');
        }       
    }

    return result;
}


int main() 
{
    Replacements morse_code;
    morse_code['a'] = ".-";
    morse_code['b'] = "-...";
    morse_code['c'] = "-.-.";
    // ...

    std::string in; 
    if (std::cin >> in)
        std::cout << Translate(morse_code, in) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but I'd use `using` instead of `typedef`, `auto` instead of `Replacements::const_iterator` and refrain from a `char const*` element type. Why not `std::string`?

Comment: `auto` and `using` requires c++11. `std::string` makes an not necessary allocation.

Comment: You already use a range-based `for` loop, which requires C++11 as well. `std::string` will *not* make any allocation if the contents are short enough and SSO is used (and even if it allocates, it doesn't matter for such tiny data). Besides, you may not always want to assign string literals but for example do something like `morse_code['a'] = { dot, minus };`, with `dot` and `minus` being char constants to allow for different representations of the morse code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong approach. Instead of trying to replace the contents of the string, it's much easier to simply create a new string:

```
std::string TranslateAll(const std::string &s)
{
    std::ostringstream o;

    for (char c:s)
        o << Translate(c);

    return o.str();
}
```

Now, you can write a much simpler

```
const char *Translate(char c)
```

All that it does is take a single character as a parameter, and returns its morse code, as a simple character string.

Much easier.

Comment: Why `ostringstream` not just a `string`?